Sorting user list by extensionArrtibute that holds the date of birth
I use the extension attribute6 to save the birth date of my users. The format is YYYY-MM-DD.
I tried:
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq "true"' -Properties extensionAttribute6 | Sort-Object extensionAttribute6.substring(4,5), Name | ft Name, extensionAttribute6

But I get:
Sort-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At D:\Scripts\getBirthdayList.ps1:1 char:75
+ ... ttribute6 | Sort-Object extensionAttribute6.substring(6,5), Name | ft ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Sort-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SortObjectCommand

The end result should look like this: (Sorted by Month, Day, Name)
Name               extensionAttribute6
----               -------------------
John Doe           1969-02-28
Albert Einstein    1897-03-14
Karl Meier         1973-12-01
James Bond         1975-12-22

Any help is appreciated.

You're trying to evaluate an expression: extensionAttribute6.SubString(4, 5) as one of the arguments for Sort-Object, in this case, you need to use a scriptblock:
Get-ADUser .... | Sort-Object { $_.extensionAttribute6.SubString(4, 5) }, Name...

See about_Calculated_Properties #Sort-Object.
Note that you can also cast datetime to the value of extensionAttribute6 instead of using .SubString:
Get-ADUser .... | Sort-Object { [datetime] $_.extensionAttribute6 }, Name...

